# IBAction cannot be set to a button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So following http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Interactive_iOS_4_iPhone_App, I'm doing the tutorial in a tabbed application template which the same thing, I have a button in the FirstViewController.xib and in the .h file, i declared a -(IBAction) selectedRow; which by clicking i'm suppose to show an alert to the user. But the problem comes from the IB where I can't right click drag, or ctrl drag or even drag the event to the File's Owner to see the action. If I do this in a single view application, it works! am i missing something here?

Comment: Have you generated the view controller and the xib file separately? Also, which version of Xcode do you use?

Comment: sch: how do i generate separately? and i'm using xcode 3.2

Comment: don't understand why is this downvoted, but either way problem solved as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the file's owner class is not set, so IB doesn't know which is the view controller and what are its actions.

Modify the **Class** parameter in file's owner from `UIViewController` into `FirstViewController`, to the correct name of your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just for convention, make your IBAction method names sound like actions.  For example, `- (IBAction)selectRow:(id)sender;`

Convention aside, you're missing IBActions require a parameter of type id as I did in my example above. Otherwise, that action won't be available to you in IB.

Comment: i tried, but the same thing, the implementation is 
-(IBAction)selectRow:(id)sender{
 int selectedIndex = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
 NSString *messages = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You selected: %@",[arrayTypes objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]];
 
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Prompt" message:messages delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];
} but when dragging the event "release inside" to the File's Owner, the icon doesn't even light up...

Comment: Did you put your new method in the header? Right click on Files owner, is your method there? Did you check to make sure the Files Owner is the FirstViewController? I just created a brand new app from scratch and followed my instructions and it worked fine.

Comment: dbrajkovic, sorry for the representation of the code, but the method declaration was in the .h file and the implementation file is in the .m file and no its not there when i right clicked on file's owner

Comment: but the weird thing is, if i start a new project of a single view application instead of a tabbed application, it works! and i did exactly the same thing!!!

Comment: problem solved it is the problem in the File's Owner that was set as UIViewController and not the class sorry can't vote you up somehow